# How to animate Ardoni death? (Songs of War (Minecraft Animation))

Tags: animation, texturing, materials

I am using Black Plasma Studios' Songs of War asset pack for the Ardoni rigs. In Songs of War, when Ardoni die, their markings lose color. Does anyone know how to do that? I tried to play around with the materials, but I can't see any way to do it except to change the skin, which I'm not sure I can animate. I want the color to gradually fade into black. I also want to be able to dim the colors, so I can show that the character is partly dead.

[image]

Comment: Hello, we'll need quite a bit more information to be able to help you :)

Comment: I added some more info about what I was trying to do. Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops lol. The answer was so easy. I wasn't in rendered mode when I was turning down the emission textures, so it didn't show.